# How can I convert NSArray<NSInteger> or NSData to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> and back in Swift?

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I'd like to convert `NSArray<NSInteger>` or `NSData` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` for use with calling a native library. The native method in C is exposed as

```
typedef struct {
    int64_t len;
    uint8_t * _Nullable data;
} ByteBuffer;

int32_t pack(ByteBuffer request, ByteBuffer * _Nullable response, ExternError * _Nullable err);
```

This becomes in Swift

```
func pack(_ request: ByteBuffer, _ response: UnsafeMutablePointer<ByteBuffer>?, _ err: UnsafeMutablePointer<ExternError>?) -> Int32

// ByteBuffer
struct ByteBuffer {
    var len: Int64
    var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?
}
```

This method would be called from React Native, so my swift definition for the input method is

```
func pack(request: Array<NSInteger>, resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock,reject:RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void { }
```

I'm not making much progress, as I struggle understanding how swift works with pointers.

```
    func pack(request: Array<NSInteger>, resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock,reject:RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {

        var req = ByteBuffer(len: Int64(request.count), data: nil)
        req.data = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: request.count)
        
        let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>([1, 2, 3])
        req.data?.assign(from: ptr, count: request.count)
        
        pack(req, _, _)
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here, I would appreciate help in any direction. The code above also produces a warning `Initialization of 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' results in a dangling pointer`.

Would it be easier to just write this in Objective C instead?

Comment: I think you're just kicking the can down the road going to Objective-C. You're gonna have to deal with it at some point. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: Note that `NSInteger` has 8 bytes on the latest iPhones, while UInt8 has only one byte. Thus the byte to byte conversion might yield unexpected results.

Comment: @Cristik good point. My assumption was that I had to convert it to NSData at some point, so that's a byte copy step that might be hard to avoid.

Comment: @Adrian I was hoping it can be done elegantly in Swift, but perhaps not. The sample code is here in case you need more context https://github.com/trinsic-id/didcomm-extension-grpc/blob/rn/react-native/ios/DidcommGrpc.swift

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get past by. Posting a solution here, in case someone else needs to work with passing pointer structures to C from Swift. The trick was to use `withUnsafeBytes` of `NSData` type or create `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` using `OpaquePointer`. This allows getting a pointer to the underlying data, without doing a copy.
Reading back the ByteBuffer was easy just by calling the corresponding initialized of `NSData`.

```swift
var request = Array<NSInteger>()
request.append(16)
request.append(2)

let requestData = NSMutableData()
for i in request {
    var i = i
    requestData.append(&i, length: 1)
}

let req = ByteBuffer(len: Int64(requestData.count), data: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(OpaquePointer(requestData.bytes)))

// If working with NSData, instead NSMutableData, the following code can be used
let req = ByteBuffer(len: Int64(requestData.count),
                     data: requestData.withUnsafeBytes { body in UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: body) })

var res = ByteBuffer()
var err = ExternError()

let code = didcomm_generate_key(req, &res, &err)

if code == 0 {
    // Response can be obtained easily using NSData ctor
    let responseData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: res.data!, length: Int(res.len), freeWhenDone: true)
}
```

Comment: If you're working on a team, I'd rename `request` to `requests`. Then, instead of `for i in request { // do stuff }`, I'd do `requests.forEach { request in // do stuff}`

Comment: I ended up doing this in Objective C anyway, since one of the dependencies (BoringSSL-gRPC) couldn't build modules in swift static library. While the solution in Swift worked, I had to go with ObjC in the end, which is little disappointing since I love Swift. Final result - https://github.com/trinsic-id/didcomm-extension-grpc/blob/2e95c9b62cfcd2a1de623a8a795516c2b3776459/react-native/react-native-didcomm-grpc/ios/DidcommGrpc.m#L102

Comment: I've been converting legacy Objective-C in my day job and I've bumped into issues like that which force rethinking of the order of conversion, etc. Congrats on figuring it out.